# How do I resolve linker errors when using PFLogInViewController with Parse in iOS?

Tags: ios, authentication, linker, parse-platform

The Parse tutorial appears to be missing one or more frameworks as evident by the linker errors that appear when you attempt to instantiate a PFLogInViewController object, like this:

```
PFLogInViewController *logInViewController = [[PFLogInViewController alloc] init]
```

Comment: Found the problem but can't answer...missing frameworks are Accounts.framework and Social.framework. Just add them to your target under Build Phases -> Link Binary with Libraries.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the example [here](https://www.parse.com/tutorials/login-and-signup-views#default). Its from parse's website and walks you through the entire creation of logging in, signing up, fb / twitter integration, and customization.

The frameworks that you likely missing are Account.framework and Social.framework